# Upload plugin to hudson not working

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

Im trying to make use of an email-ext plugin for hudson that was developed by chetan [here.](http://techkriti.wordpress.com/2008/08/30/using-groovy-with-hudson-to-send-rich-text-email/)

It allows for rich text email to be used in the content of email notifications from hudson.

The problem is I cant seem to upload the .hpi file

I go to Hudson -> Manage Hudson -> Manage Plugins -> Advanced browse to .hpi file then click upload. After a few seconds I am taken to the manage plugins page. There is no output to the terminal and after restarting hudson there is no sign of the new plugin. Has anyone else had this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Nope I didn't have that problem so far. Check the plugins folder of your Hudson installation. It should contain the hpi file that you uploaded and a folder (same name than hpi file) with the exploded version. if both are not present, just drop the hpi file in the plugins folder and restart Hudson. It should than extract the hpi file.

I skimmed over the blog entry that you linked. It mentions that it is a modification of the email-ext plugin. Check if you have the ext plugin installed. If yes, remove it and see if the hpi file installs correctly. Just wondering if it might be a version problem (that the ext is newer than the groovy-email plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Name the packages like maven's `Group-ID`

I.e. if you have `org.wan-ja-wum` as group id, your Build-Extension must be in package `org.wan_ja_wum`.